# Sencha Touch 1.* How to load data in nested list before view it?

Tags: proxy, sencha-touch, nested-lists

In my NestedList I load data by proxy in TreeStore. Then I change url in proxy and read it and show my updated NestedList, but first show the old data, but only after a time they were updated on the screen. Help please!

Comment: Can I clean data in nested list before render it with new data?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
app.stores.architecturalPlaceStore.proxy.url = urlString+"qrcode/load-arch-places?pid="+window.localStorage.getItem("cur-root-nid");
app.stores.architecturalPlaceStore.read();
app.stores.architecturalPlaceStore.on("read",function(store,records,index){
                                    Ext.dispatch(
                                            {
                                                controller: 'controller',
                                                action: 'archPlaces',
                                                historyUrl: 'archPlaces',
                                                animation: {
                                                    type: 'slide'
                                                }
                                            });

                                })
```

and this to controller:

```
archPlaces:function()
    {            
        console.log("Arch places function");
        if ( ! this.archPlaceSelector)
        {
            globalMask[2].show();
            this.archPlaceSelector = this.render({
                xtype: 'ArchPlaceSelector',
                renderHidden: true
            });
        } 
        this.application.viewport.setActiveItem(this.archPlaceSelector);
    },
```

**"load" event for TreeStore in Sencha Touch 1.* not firing!! It`s bug!**